# Using Array data type in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica, presto

I am extracting category information from a free text and writing a bunch of case statements for each category. In presto, I am able to create an array with the col names and unnest the data to change multiple categories to 1 col and the categories as rows. Eg query below:

```
WITH target as (
     SELECT 
     case when a = b then 'test1' else null end as "test1",
     case when c = d then 'test2' else null end as "test2",
     case when c = d then 'test3' else null end as "test3",
     case when c = d then 'test4' else null end as "test4",
     ,name, id, user_id
     FROM test_table
              ),
nest1 as (
     SELECT ARRAY[test1, test2, test3, test4] as test_categoies
     ,name,id
     ,user_id
     FROM target
         ),
nest2 as (
     SELECT *
     FROM nest1
     CROSS JOIN UNNEST(test_categories) AS t(final_categories) 
     -- this fans out the array so each category is in its own row
         )
SELECT *
FROM nest 2
```

NOTE: This query runs well on presto but fails on Vertica as arrays are not supported in Vertica. Are there any alternatives I can use here?

Comment: Asking a relational database for arrays, in my opinion is like asking if an airplane has four-wheel drive. Relational means fixed tabular format. This rigidity encourages stability, quality, speed, reliability and recognisability. I'm pretty sure there is a different way to do it using a relational approach. After all you use CASE WHEN expressions and a hard-wired array - with a fixed number of elements, where you already commit to a number of columns. This suggests you don't have to resort to variable list elements. Can you give us an example input table and a sample final output expected?